# multiple numpy dot products without a loop

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matrix

Is it possible to compute several dot products without a loop?
say you have the following:

```
a = randn(100, 3, 3)
b = randn(100, 3, 3)
```

I want to get an array `z` of shape (100, 3, 3) such that for all `i`

```
z[i, ...] == dot(a[i, ...], b[i, ...])
```

in other words, which verifies:

```
for va, vb, vz in izip(a, b, z):
    assert (vq == dot(va, vb)).all()
```

The straightforward solution would be:

```
z = array([dot(va, vb) for va, vb in zip(a, b)])
```

which uses an implicit loop (list comprehension + array).

Is there a more efficient way to compute z?

Comment: In Python 3.5, it'll be `a @ b` (unless things have changed since [PEP 465](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)). Unfortunately, `dot` doesn't work that way. I don't know why.

Answer (score 7):

`np.einsum` can be useful here. Try running this copy+pasteable code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(100, 3, 3)
b = np.random.randn(100, 3, 3)

z = np.einsum("ijk, ikl -> ijl", a, b)

z2 = np.array([ai.dot(bi) for ai, bi in zip(a, b)])

assert (z == z2).all()
```

`einsum` is compiled code and runs very fast, even compared to `np.tensordot` (which doesn't apply here exactly, but often is applicable). Here are some stats:

```
In [8]: %timeit z = np.einsum("ijk, ikl -> ijl", a, b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 105 us per loop


In [9]: %timeit z2 = np.array([ai.dot(bi) for ai, bi in zip(a, b)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop
```

Comment: tensordot very much applies here; simply contract over axes=[[2],[1]]. Though I suspect einsum to be faster, considering the large number of small contractions performed. tensordot is more optimized for contractions over large dimensions I believe.

Comment: Eelco, summing using those axes does not give the same result as the einsum.

Comment: `np.tensordot` would do a sort of outer product, multiplying every matrix in `a` with every matrix in `b`, giving rise to 2 axes of size 100. The desired result is the diagonal of that, so `np.tensordot` calculates too many coefficients.

Answer (score 6):

Try Einstein summation in numpy:

```
z = np.einsum('...ij,...jk->...ik', a, b)
```

It's elegant and does not require you to write a loop, as you requested.
It gives me a factor of 4.8 speed increase on my system:

```
%timeit z = array([dot(va, vb) for va, vb in zip(a, b)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 454 µs per loop

%timeit z = np.einsum('...ij,...jk->...ik', a, b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.6 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution still uses a loop, but is faster because it avoids unnecessary creation of temp arrays, by using the `out` arg of `dot`:

```
def dotloop(a,b):
    res = empty(a.shape)
    for ai,bi,resi in zip(a,b,res):
        np.dot(ai, bi, out = resi)
    return res

%timeit dotloop(a,b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 453 us per loop
%timeit array([dot(va, vb) for va, vb in zip(a, b)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 843 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, I want to add that:

```
np.einsum("ijk, ijk -> ij", a, b)
```

Is suitable for a related case I encountered, where you have two 3D arrays consisting of matching 2D fields of 2D vectors (points or directions). This gives a kind of "element-wise" dot product between those 2D vectors.

For example:

```
np.einsum("ijk, ijk -> ij", [[[1,2],[3,4]]], [[[5,6],[7,8]]])
# => array([[17, 53]])
```

Where:

```
np.dot([1,2],[5,6])
# => 17
np.dot([3,4],[7,8])
# => 53
```