# Replace dot product for loop Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nlp, self

I am trying to replace the dot product for loop using something faster like NumPy

I did research on dot product and kind of understand and can get it working with toy data in a few ways in but not 100% when it comes to implementing it for actual use with a data frame.

I looked at these and other SO threads to no luck [avoide loop dot product, matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006176/dot-product-of-subarrays-without-for-loop) and [dot product subarrays without for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006176/dot-product-of-subarrays-without-for-loop) and [multiple numpy dot products without a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090889/multiple-numpy-dot-products-without-a-loop)

**looking to do something like this which works with toy numbers in np array**

```
u1 =np.array([1,2,3])
u2 =np.array([2,3,4])
v1.dot(v2)
20
```

```
u1 =np.array([1,2,3])
u2 =np.array([2,3,4])
(u1 * u2).sum()
20
```

```
u1 =np.array([1,2,3])
u2 =np.array([2,3,4])
sum([x1*x2 for x1, x2 in zip (u1, u2)])
20
```

**this is the current working get dot product**

I would like to do this with out the for loop

```
def get_dot_product(self, courseid1, courseid2, unit_vectors):
    u1 = unit_vectors[courseid1]
    u2 = unit_vectors[courseid2]
    dot_product = 0.0
    for dimension in u1:
        if dimension in u2:
            dot_product += u1[dimension] * u2[dimension]
    return dot_product
```

** code**

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # coding: utf-8
    
    
    
    class SearchRecommendationSystem:
    
        def __init__(self):
            pass
    
 
    def get_bag_of_words(self, titles_lines):
        bag_of_words = {}
        for index, row in titles_lines.iterrows():
            courseid, course_bag_of_words = self.get_course_bag_of_words(row)
            for word in course_bag_of_words:
                word = str(word).strip()  # added
                if word not in bag_of_words:
                    bag_of_words[word] = course_bag_of_words[word]
                else:
                    bag_of_words[word] += course_bag_of_words[word]
        return bag_of_words

    def get_course_bag_of_words(self, line):
        course_bag_of_words = {}
        courseid = line['courseid']
        title = line['title'].lower()
        description = line['description'].lower()
        wordlist = title.split() + description.split()
        if len(wordlist) >= 10:
            for word in wordlist:
                word = str(word).strip()  # added
                if word not in course_bag_of_words:
                    course_bag_of_words[word] = 1
                else:
                    course_bag_of_words[word] += 1
        return courseid, course_bag_of_words

    def get_sorted_results(self, d):
        kv_list = d.items()
        vk_list = []
        for kv in kv_list:
            k, v = kv
            vk = v, k
            vk_list.append(vk)
        vk_list.sort()
        vk_list.reverse()
        k_list = []
        for vk in vk_list[:10]:
            v, k = vk
            k_list.append(k)
        return k_list

    def get_keywords(self, titles_lines, bag_of_words):
        n = sum(bag_of_words.values())
        keywords = {}
        for index, row in titles_lines.iterrows():
            courseid, course_bag_of_words = self.get_course_bag_of_words(row)
            term_importance = {}
            for word in course_bag_of_words:
                word = str(word).strip()  # extra
                tf_course = (float(course_bag_of_words[word]) / sum(course_bag_of_words.values()))
                tf_overall = float(bag_of_words[word]) / n
                term_importance[word] = tf_course / tf_overall
            keywords[str(courseid)] = self.get_sorted_results(term_importance)
        return keywords

    def get_inverted_index(self, keywords):
        inverted_index = {}
        for courseid in keywords:
            for keyword in keywords[courseid]:
                if keyword not in inverted_index:
                    keyword = str(keyword).strip()  # added
                    inverted_index[keyword] = []
                inverted_index[keyword].append(courseid)
        return inverted_index

    def get_search_results(self, query_terms, keywords, inverted_index):
        search_results = {}
        for term in query_terms:
            term = str(term).strip()
            if term in inverted_index:
                for courseid in inverted_index[term]:
                    if courseid not in search_results:
                        search_results[courseid] = 0.0
                    search_results[courseid] += (
                            1 / float(keywords[courseid].index(term) + 1) *
                            1 / float(query_terms.index(term) + 1)
                    )
        sorted_results = self.get_sorted_results(search_results)
        return sorted_results

    def get_titles(self, titles_lines):
        titles = {}
        for index, row in titles_lines.iterrows():
            titles[row['courseid']] = row['title'][:60]
        return titles
    
        def get_unit_vectors(self, keywords, categories_lines):
            norm = 1.884
            cat = {}
            subcat = {}
            for line in categories_lines[1:]:
                courseid_, category, subcategory = line.split('\t')
                cat[courseid_] = category.strip()
                subcat[courseid_] = subcategory.strip()
            unit_vectors = {}
            for courseid in keywords:
                u = {}
                if courseid in cat:
                    u[cat[courseid]] = 1 / norm
                    u[subcat[courseid]] = 1 / norm
                for keyword in keywords[courseid]:
                    u[keyword] = (1 / float(keywords[courseid].index(keyword) + 1) / norm)
                unit_vectors[courseid] = u
            return unit_vectors
    
        def get_dot_product(self, courseid1, courseid2, unit_vectors):
            u1 = unit_vectors[courseid1]
            u2 = unit_vectors[courseid2]
            dot_product = 0.0
            for dimension in u1:
                if dimension in u2:
                    dot_product += u1[dimension] * u2[dimension]
            return dot_product
    
        def get_recommendation_results(self, seed_courseid, keywords, inverted_index, unit_vectors):
            courseids = []
            seed_courseid = str(seed_courseid).strip()
            for keyword in keywords[seed_courseid]:
                for courseid in inverted_index[keyword]:
                    if courseid not in courseids and courseid != seed_courseid:
                        courseids.append(courseid)
    
            dot_products = {}
            for courseid in courseids:
                dot_products[courseid] = self.get_dot_product(seed_courseid, courseid, unit_vectors)
            sorted_results = self.get_sorted_results(dot_products)
            return sorted_results
    
    
        def Final(self):
            print("Reading Title file.......")
            titles_lines = open('s2-titles.txt', encoding="utf8").readlines()
            print("Reading Category file.......")
            categories_lines = open('s2-categories.tsv', encoding = "utf8").readlines()
            print("Getting Supported Functions Data")
            bag_of_words = self.get_bag_of_words(titles_lines)
            keywords = self.get_keywords(titles_lines, bag_of_words)
            inverted_index = self.get_inverted_index(keywords)
            titles = self.get_titles(titles_lines)
    
            print("Getting Unit Vectors")
            unit_vectors = self.get_unit_vectors(keywords=keywords, categories_lines=categories_lines)
    
            #Search Part
            print("\n ############# Started Search Query System ############# \n")
            query = input('Input your search query: ')
            while query != '':
                query_terms = query.split()
                search_sorted_results = self.get_search_results(query_terms, keywords, inverted_index)
                print(f"==> search results for query: {query.split()}")
    
                for search_result in search_sorted_results:
                    print(f"{search_result.strip()} - {str(titles[search_result]).strip()}")
    
                #ask again for query or quit the while loop if no query is given
                query = input('Input your search query [hit return to finish]: ')
    
    
            print("\n ############# Started Recommendation Algorithm System ############# \n")
            # Recommendation ALgorithm Part
            seed_courseid = (input('Input your seed courseid: '))
            while seed_courseid != '':
                seed_courseid = str(seed_courseid).strip()
                recom_sorted_results = self.get_recommendation_results(seed_courseid, keywords, inverted_index, unit_vectors)
                print('==> recommendation results:')
                for rec_result in recom_sorted_results:
                    print(f"{rec_result.strip()} - {str(titles[rec_result]).strip()}")
                    get_dot_product_ = self.get_dot_product(seed_courseid, str(rec_result).strip(), unit_vectors)
                    print(f"Dot Product Value: {get_dot_product_}")
                seed_courseid = (input('Input seed courseid [hit return to finish]:'))
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        obj = SearchRecommendationSystem()
        obj.Final()
```

**s2-categories.tsv**

```
    courseid    category    subcategory
    21526   Design  3D & Animation
    153082  Marketing   Advertising
    225436  Marketing   Affiliate Marketing
    19482   Office Productivity Apple
    33883   Office Productivity Apple
    59526   IT & Software   Operating Systems
    29219   Personal Development    Career Development
    35057   Personal Development    Career Development
    40751   Personal Development    Career Development
    65210   Personal Development    Career Development
    234414  Personal Development    Career Development
```

**Example of how s2-titles.txt looks**

```
courseidXXXYYYZZZtitleXXXYYYZZZdescription
3586XXXYYYZZZLearning Tools for Mrs  B's Science Classes This is a series of lessons that will introduce students to the learning tools that will be utilized throughout the schoXXXYYYZZZThis is a series of lessons that will introduce students to the learning tools that will be utilized throughout the school year  The use of these tools serves multiple purposes       1  Allow the teacher to give immediate and meaningful feedback on work that is in progress    2  Allow students to have access to content and materials when outside the classroom    3  Provide a variety of methods for students to experience learning materials    4  Provide a variety of methods for students to demonstrate learning    5  Allow for more time sensitive correction  grading and reflections on concepts that are assessed
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with how you would run `get_dot_product`?

Comment: The fast numpy `dot` uses numeric arrays and does most of the work in compiled libraries like `BLAS`.  It will also work for some object dtype arrays, but will be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently `unit_vectors` is a dictionary, from which you extract to 2 values, `u1` and `u2`.

But what are those?  Evidently dicts as well (this iteration would not make sense with a list):

```
for dimension in u1:
    if dimension in u2:
        dot_product += u1[dimension] * u2[dimension]
```

But what is `u1[dimension]`?  A list?  An array.

Normally `dict` are access by `key` as you do here.  There isn't a numpy style "vectorization".  `vals = list(u1.values())` gets a lists of all values, and conceivably that could be made into an array (if the elements are right)

```
 arr1 = np.array(list(u1.values()))
```

and a `np.dot(arr1, arr2)` might work

You'll get the best answers if you give small concrete examples - with real working data (and skip the complex generating code).  Focus on the core of the problem, so we can grasp the issue with a 30 second read!

===

Looking more in depth at your `dot` function; this replicates the core (I think).  Initially I missed the fact that you aren't iterating on `u2` keys, but rather seeking matching ones.

```
def foo(dd):
    x = 0
    u1 = dd['u1']
    u2 = dd['u2']
    for k in u1:
        if k in u2:
            x += u1[k]*u2[k]
    return x
```

Then making a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
In [30]: keys=list('abcde'); values=[1,2,3,4,5]
In [31]: adict = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,values)}
In [32]: dd = {'u1':adict, 'u2':adict}

In [41]: dd
Out[41]: 
{'u1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5},
 'u2': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}}
In [42]: foo(dd)
Out[42]: 55
```

In this case the subdictionaries match, so we get the same value with a simple array `dot`:

```
In [43]: np.dot(values,values)
Out[43]: 55
```

But if `u2` was different, with different key/value pairs, and possibly different keys the result will be different.  I don't see a way around the iterative access by keys. The sum-of-products part of the job is minor compared to the dictionary access.

```
In [44]: dd['u2'] = {'e':3, 'f':4, 'a':3}
In [45]: foo(dd)
Out[45]: 18
```

We could construct other data structures that are more suitable to a fast `dot` like calculation.  But that's another topic.

Comment: I readded full code it works as is, it's not using anything other than python its 5 years got it working in python 3+ but trying to update to a more modern approach.

Comment: I didnt know how to pull out the values for unit_vectors[courseid1] and unit_vectors[courseid2]) . I wanted to just add those values = to u1 and u2 to have concise question.

Answer (score 1):

Modified method

```
def get_dot_product(self, courseid1, courseid2, unit_vectors):
    # u1 = unit_vectors[courseid1]
    # u2 = unit_vectors[courseid2]
    # dimensions = set(u1).intersection(set(u2))
    # dot_product = sum(u1[dimension] * u2.get(dimension, 0) for dimension in dimensions)

    u1 = unit_vectors[courseid1]
    u2 = unit_vectors[courseid2]
    dot_product = sum(u1[dimension] * u2.get(dimension, 0) for dimension in u2)
    return dot_product
```

Comment: I just tried that but throws a error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'dict`

Comment: `dot_product = u1.dot(u2)` which would be on this line of code.

Comment: I just updated the code, commented line also will work fine